# Tapestry sample exception

Tags: tapestry

I download a sample of tapestry and run it on the tomcat server,though it is very simple,the following exception occurs:
HTTP Status 500 - Exception constructing service 'PagePool': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(PageLoader, ComponentMessagesSource, ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1737) (for service 'PagePool'): Exception constructing service 'PageLoader': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1760) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
type Exception report

message Exception constructing service 'PagePool': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(PageLoader, ComponentMessagesSource, ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1737) (for service 'PagePool'): Exception constructing service 'PageLoader': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1760) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'PagePool': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(PageLoader, ComponentMessagesSource, ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1737) (for service 'PagePool'): Exception constructing service 'PageLoader': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1760) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:76)
    $PagePool_15586255420._delegate($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    $PagePool_15586255420.checkout($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:43)
    $RequestPageCache_1558625541f.get($RequestPageCache_1558625541f.java)
    $RequestPageCache_155862553f2.get($RequestPageCache_155862553f2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:47)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:513)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:79)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:93)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:84)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:77)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:106)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    $RequestHandler_15586255407.service($RequestHandler_15586255407.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$12.service(TapestryModule.java:891)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:164)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(PageLoader, ComponentMessagesSource, ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1737) (for service 'PagePool'): Exception constructing service 'PageLoader': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1760) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:88)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:54)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:51)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:61)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    $PagePool_15586255420._delegate($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    $PagePool_15586255420.checkout($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:43)
    $RequestPageCache_1558625541f.get($RequestPageCache_1558625541f.java)
    $RequestPageCache_155862553f2.get($RequestPageCache_155862553f2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:47)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:513)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:79)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:93)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:84)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:77)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:106)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    $RequestHandler_15586255407.service($RequestHandler_15586255407.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$12.service(TapestryModule.java:891)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:164)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'PageLoader': Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1760) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:76)
    $PageLoader_15586255421._delegate($PageLoader_15586255421.java)
    $PageLoader_15586255421.addInvalidationListener($PageLoader_15586255421.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(TapestryModule.java:1741)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:54)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:51)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:61)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    $PagePool_15586255420._delegate($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    $PagePool_15586255420.checkout($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:43)
    $RequestPageCache_1558625541f.get($RequestPageCache_1558625541f.java)
    $RequestPageCache_155862553f2.get($RequestPageCache_155862553f2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:47)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:513)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:79)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:93)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:84)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:77)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:106)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    $RequestHandler_15586255407.service($RequestHandler_15586255407.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$12.service(TapestryModule.java:891)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:164)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(ServiceResources) (at TapestryModule.java:1760) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:88)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:54)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:51)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:61)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    $PageLoader_15586255421._delegate($PageLoader_15586255421.java)
    $PageLoader_15586255421.addInvalidationListener($PageLoader_15586255421.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(TapestryModule.java:1741)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:54)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:51)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:61)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    $PagePool_15586255420._delegate($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    $PagePool_15586255420.checkout($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:43)
    $RequestPageCache_1558625541f.get($RequestPageCache_1558625541f.java)
    $RequestPageCache_155862553f2.get($RequestPageCache_155862553f2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:47)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:513)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:79)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:93)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:84)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:77)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:106)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    $RequestHandler_15586255407.service($RequestHandler_15586255407.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$12.service(TapestryModule.java:891)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:164)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking constructor org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.PageLoaderImpl(ComponentTemplateSource, PageElementFactory, LinkFactory, PersistentFieldManager, ComponentClassResolver) (at PageLoaderImpl.java:41) (for service 'PageLoader'): Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:62)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceResourcesImpl.autobuild(ServiceResourcesImpl.java:123)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.buildPageLoader(TapestryModule.java:1760)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:54)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:51)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:61)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    $PageLoader_15586255421._delegate($PageLoader_15586255421.java)
    $PageLoader_15586255421.addInvalidationListener($PageLoader_15586255421.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule.build(TapestryModule.java:1741)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:76)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:54)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:51)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:61)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    $PagePool_15586255420._delegate($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    $PagePool_15586255420.checkout($PagePool_15586255420.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.RequestPageCacheImpl.get(RequestPageCacheImpl.java:43)
    $RequestPageCache_1558625541f.get($RequestPageCache_1558625541f.java)
    $RequestPageCache_155862553f2.get($RequestPageCache_155862553f2.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:47)
    $RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.handleRequestException($RequestExceptionHandler_1558625540c.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:513)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:79)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:93)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:84)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:77)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:106)
    $RequestHandler_15586255410.service($RequestHandler_15586255410.java)
    $RequestHandler_15586255407.service($RequestHandler_15586255407.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.services.TapestryModule$12.service(TapestryModule.java:891)
    org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    $HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_15586255406.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255408.java)
    $HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_15586255405.java)
    org.apache.tapestry.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:164)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error building service proxy for service 'LinkFactory' (at org.apache.tapestry.internal.services.LinkFactoryImpl(Request, Response, ComponentInvocationMap, RequestPageCache, RequestPathOptimizer, PageRenderQueue, ContextValueEncoder) (at LinkFactoryImpl.java:69)): Unable to add method org.apache.tapestry.Link createPageLink(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) to class $LinkFactory_15586255425: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.create(ModuleImpl.java:251)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.findOrCreate(ModuleImpl.java:163)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.ModuleImpl.getService(ModuleImpl.java:91)
    org.apache.tapestry.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getService(RegistryImpl.java:293)
    ...

---

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you debug _at all_?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tapestry are you using? The "PagePool" went away with Tapestry 5.2, which was released way back in 2010. Maybe you have an old Tapestry JAR on your classpath?